# cannot import name picamera

Tags: raspbian, python

I bought raspberry pi camera and it works, but when i use python to use the camera return Error: cannot import name picamera.
I have install python3-picamera.and this is python programming:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
camera = PiCamera() 
camera.start_preview()
time.sleep(10)
camera.capture('/home/pi/image.jpg')
camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] to include the full error message/stack trace? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Methinks too many picamera's. :)  Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import picamera
import time

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
   camera.resolution = (640, 480)
   camera.start_preview()
   time.sleep(10)
   camera.capture('/home/pi/image.jpg')
   camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it return nameError: name camera is not define.

Comment: Thanks all working now, I find my mistake your code was spot on. thanks

Comment: @FarzadBazrafshan please note that you can accept a helpful answer by ticking the check mark next to it, see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that have the same issue, make sure you didn't create any file named picamera.py.  If you did, then the import will try to reference your file instead of the package.

I fixed it by changing the file name from PiCamera.py and delete anything in the directory that was called PiCamera.*

Comment: I don't see a fine named PiCamera in the question.

Comment: yeah, im just assuming that, because i have exactly the same code from some online tutorial

Comment: naming your first file picamera is a pretty easy mistake to make (I made it too, lol)